# What does it mean if an event is Signaled or not?

Tags: windows, events, signals

In Windows especially, is it true that the thread will exit if the event is **signaled**. What does it mean when an event is **signaled**?

Comment: Do you possibly confuse an signalling a Windows event object with a POSIX signal? Those are entirely different things. An event object is an inter-thread synchronisation object, something not unlike a semaphore, which you can acquire and release ("signal") in the same way. There is no reason why a thread should exit because of that.

Comment: @Damon,Will the sub threads exit if the main thread dies?

Comment: I'm going to answer "NO" although the correct answer would be "YES". Do not rely on such a thing to happen. Make the other threads exit in a controlled, defined way. Signal threads and have them return, don't kill them, wait for your threads to exit, and clean up memory that you have allocated. Although this is usually not necessary, do it anyway. If you have the habit of doing everything the lazy way, sooner or later you'll find yourself in a debugging nightmare, once you encounter a situation where the "it works anyway" assumption does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must understand what an event is. Any performance of UI or programmatic action can be called as event. For eg, clicking a mouse button or pressing a keyboard key, etc.

Now, an event is signalled means the occurance of such an event.

Comment: While technically true, the OP is talking about [the synchronization primitive called "events" in the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655.aspx), not about event-driven programming.